# Regex for removing starting and ending spaces within < > and </> PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which have data like this:

```
<div style="float: right;"><span class='abcd'>      test data here     </sapn></div>
```

I want the out put as :

```
<div style="float: right;"><span class='abcd'>test data here</sapn></div>
```

So far what I have tried is as in regex php,

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $data);
preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/', '', $data);
```

But its not giving me the desired result

Comment: Use trim function ? [Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: RegExp is not suitable for parsing and changing HTML text. Use a parser class for HTML and then trim the textnode.

Comment: is your input contains \n characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(<([^ ]+)[^<>]+>)\s*([^<]+?)\s*(<\/\2>)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1$3$4`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vF0kU2/5

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', '', $data);
```

Comment: maybe `$data = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', '', $data);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right. But `preg_replace` **does not modify the argument. rather it returns a modified string**

So you can write something like

```
$data = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data);
```

will give `$data` as

```
<div style="float: right;"><span class='abcd'>test data here</sapn></div>
```

**Note**

You must replace with a space `' '` so as to preserve a single space

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below.

```
preg_replace('~(?<=<)[^<>]*(?=>)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?<=>)\h+|\h+(?=<))~', '', $data);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mI5dQ1/6)

`\h+` matches one or more horizontal spaces.

Answer (score 0):

With DOMDocument:

```
$html = '<div style="float: right;"><span class="abcd">      test data here     </span></div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD|LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$textNodeList = $xpath->query('//text()');

foreach ($textNodeList as $textNode) {
    $textNode->nodeValue = trim($textNode->nodeValue);
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```